# Half the text or number is hidden when padding is used on <input type="number">

Tags: html, css

This is the CSS I used on an input typed number. Is there a way to avoid it from hiding half of the text (number, in this case). I use firefox as my browser and I wrote this on codepen.io. I just checked how it works on chrome and it works perfectly. Firefox or codepen is the problem, I guess. This is the link to my pen. Open it in Firefox and try to type some numbers or text in Age's input field. That should show what problem I am facing. Just in case it doesn't, let me know. I appreciate all the help, thank you.

https://codepen.io/srushti335/pen/dQQBvX/

```css
    input[type="number"]{
      height: 30px;
      width: 40%;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 2px solid gray;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="number"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add your html codes. We can't see your problem without html codes.

Comment: @srushti mund I show all text can you explain your issuse please

Comment: Running it here works okay! In any case strike a balance between height and padding!

Comment: Its working fine.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed height on that element, so your padding top/bottom causes an actual height for the number characters that's too low to fit the characters in it. I would use the padding only for left and right, i.e. change the padding value to `padding: 0px 10px;`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQdRZo

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But I have one more question. Why is this the case only for that specific type of input and not for the other two(name and email) above it?

Comment: I guess that's brwoser-dependent, i.e. the way the characters are on top or below the padding area - in some browsers not even your initial code shows any problems

Answer (score 2):

The input's padding is more. Its covering text. If there's a fixed height padding tries to accommodate inside of that height. This is why its covering the text.

```
input #age {
    padding: 0;
}
```

OR

Increase the height to accomodate the text as well as the padding

```
input {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? It actually works. If there's any problem please explain in comments before downvoting

Comment: This works in the codepen, but not on the code shown in the question.  The answer also doesn't explain *why* this fixes the codepen (padding doesn't generally clip the contents of the element.)

Comment: @DanielBeck It does clip when you have a fixed height set.

Comment: That would be exactly the sort of explanation that's missing from the answer, yes!

Comment: Sir, I want some padding inside the input field with number type(Age). Input fields with email and name types didn't act that way. They are working fine even after applying padding to them. Is there any other way?

Comment: The placeholder is covered by the padding. So, just use `#age` and set padding to zero.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, sir. It helped me understand stuff I didn't know before.